# Server failed to authenticate the request. (Status Code: 401; Error Code: NoAuthenticationInformation)]

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Currently following the instruction for loading the data from Azure. Option no 1.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-azure-config.html

The storage integration with a service principal.

I'm keep getting the error :

Failure using stage area. Cause: [Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the
information in the www-authenticate header. (Status Code: 401; Error Code: NoAuthenticationInformation)]

I Azure I can see that there are AuthorizationErrors. Snowflake is reaching Azure but Azure thinks that it can't give access.

Anyone an idea?

Hennie

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it looks like an access issue. Couple ideas:

1. Perhaps the token expired?  Try regenerating the SAS token and then recreate the Azure external stage with it.
2. Do you have a firewall on your Azure storage?
   If so, follow these steps:  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-azure-allow.html#allowing-the-vnet-subnet-ids

Comment: SAS token works fine. Just tried that with no problem. Will check the firewall.

Comment: Hmm, very strange then as all should work.  Perhaps try re-creating the stage or test with a different container:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-azure-create-stage.html#creating-an-azure-stage

Comment: I can pass the STAGE with direct access to the container   COPY INTO Public.DimDate 
FROM 'azure://stgsnowflake.blob.core.windows.net/advworkscontainer/DimDate.csv'; This will give also an 401 error.

Comment: Reading https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-storage-integration.html, warning block..."Recreating a storage integration (using CREATE OR REPLACE STORAGE INTEGRATION) breaks the association between the storage integration and any stage that references it.". Think that might be the case. CREATE OR REPLACE seems not a good idea.

Comment: Yep that was the problem. Use ALTER STAGE AZURE_STAGE SET STORAGE_INTEGRATION = AzureAdvWorksContainer; for setting the hidden link between the STAGE en de STORAGE_INTEGRATION!